# Tizen: how to run anything on emulator?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator

I installed Tizen Studio, and in Package Manager I've also installed Emulator for Tizen v4.0:

[image]

I'm trying to test one (any) of the samples (for Wearable v4.0 and selecting Native): for example `Stopwatch`:

[image]

But in `Project properties > C/C++ Build > Tizen Settings > Platform` there is no X86 architecture:

[image]

Therefore, whenever I try running the sample application on the emulator (which is obviously x86-based), I get this error message:

[image]

I have tried to ask a question on their forum: https://developer.tizen.org/forums/native-application-development/active?langswitch=en, but I couldn't register because they are not capable to send the activation email to my GMail address...

Any help is really appreciated. I think somehow I have to put the x86 arch into the settings, just I have no idea how this Tizen Studio really works because they even don't have a straightforward documentation.

Comment: Could you share your OS information?

Comment: Sure, sorry. I'm trying to do this on Windows 10.

Comment: 4.0 (Tizen Studio + Native 4.0 Wearable sample, build and debug) works correctly.. with my PC

Comment: How about to use more recent dev environment? I recommend to use Visual Studio + Tizen Plugin + Tizen SDK (need to install 5.5 wearable using package manager) + .NET (C# language) + Xamarin.Forms as UI framework. In this case, you can use special feature for Wearable device - Tizen.CircularUI.

Comment: Do You have both `arm` *and* `x86` in Tizen Settings > Architecture?

Comment: plz, visit here! for .NET experience with Tizen. https://docs.tizen.org/application/dotnet/

Comment: I dont want Xamarin, C/C++ is better suited for my needs.

Comment: And, besides of that, my watch is on version 4.0

Comment: I have both (x86 and arm). I recommend to uninstall all and install it again using package manager.. sorry.. T.T

Comment: You might want to add the reinstall idea as an answer and I'll accept that. Completely removed everything related to version 4.0 and reinstalled. Now there is x86, and builder can change to it, so emulator is working now intended. Thanks.

Comment: Oh. good news! If you have some trouble to use 4.0 Native, try to use .NET (supported since Tizen 4.0)